# Writing a recursive function which iterates through an unknown depth of nested loops

Tags: javascript, recursion, iteration

Given an array of values:

```
var values = new Array(); 

array.push(2);
array.push(3);
array.push(4);
```

I'd like to create an iterative function which can store every possible combination of values, for any length of array.

For example, in this case the possible values would be (1,1,1)(1,1,2)(1,1,3)(1,1,4)(1,2,1)(1,2,2)(1,2,3)(1,2,4)(2,1,1)(2,1,2)(2,1,3)(2,1,4)(2,2,1)(2,2,2)(2,2,3)(2,2,4)

I know that to do this I need to use an recursive function, which will go a level deeper and call the function again if the maximum depth has not been reached...

I know where to start is (probably, I think)

```
function iterativeLoop(level, depth) {
    for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if(level < depth) {
            iterativeloop(level+1, depth);
        }
        else if (level=depth) {
        }
   }
}
```

I'm not sure how I can access the 'upper' levels once the function is called deeper though... i.e. I'm not sure how to access (1,2,4) and not just (?,?,4)

I hope that makes sense?

(Sorry I know my title isn't very good, I couldn't think how to concisely explain it)

Comment: The word you're looking for is "recursive", not "iterative" (may help if you're searching).  If I get a minute I'll write up an example.

Comment: Also, probably not necessary.  Writing up an answer now.

Comment: You never really **have** to write a recursive function.

Comment: True, but there are times when it's more or less suited to the problem.  I think this is a case where it's less.

Comment: the first piece of code means just `var values = [2, 3, 4];` or am i missing something?

Comment: Yes, it does just mean that, sorry, I should have put that to be clearer.

Comment: i still wonder where the `1` comes from =/

Comment: He wants an array of arrays, where the first value could be 1 or 2, the second value could be 1, 2, or 3, and the third value could be 1, 2, 3, or 4

Comment: Can you provide some structure of array, i mean example of the result which you expect

Comment: I was just thinking about this question again, and it occurred to me to check the actual relative performance of the iterative solution vs. the recursive solution: http://jsperf.com/iterative-vs-recursive-so

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure how I can access the 'upper' levels once the function is called deeper though... i.e. I'm not sure how to access (1,2,4) and not just (?,?,4)

You will need to pass them on, e.g. in an array.

> ```
> for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
> ```

This should not be the outer iteration to perform, unless you want to construct a two-dimensional array of results in a simple nested loop (see below). Instead, you want `value.length` to be the depth you are recursing to. On every recursion level, you will iterate from 1 to `values[level]` then. And instead of passing a `level`, we will pass an array of the current state (the question marks from above) whose length is the level.

```
var values = [2,3,4];
function recurse(state) {
    var level = state.length;
    var depth = values.length;
    if (level == depth) {
        console.log.apply(console, state); // or whatever you want to do
    } else {
        for (var i=1; i<=values[level]; i++) {
            state.push(i); // save current question mark
                           // notice state.length = level + 1 now
            recurse(state); // enter next level
            state.pop(); // delete it after we're so state doesn't grow infinitely :-)
        }
    }
}
recurse([]);
```

---

If you want to use your iteration over the values, you can do so by adding more and more states to a result array (growing by one value each level), which in the end will contain all possible combinations:

```
var values = [2,3,4];
var result = [[]]; // one empty state at level 0
for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    var reslen = result.length,
        val = values[i];
    var mult = []; // will become the new result with a length of (reslen * val)
    for (var j=0; j<reslen; j++) {
        for (var k=1; k<=val; k++) {
            var state = result[j].slice(); // make a copy
            state.push(k);
            mult.push(state);
        }
    }
    result = mult;
}

// logging the `result` on each level will show us
// 0 - [[]]
// 1 - [[1],[2]]
// 2 - [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3]]
// 3 - [[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,1,3],[1,1,4],[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,3,1],[1,3,2],[1,3,3],[1,3,4],[2,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,1,3],[2,1,4],[2,2,1],[2,2,2],[2,2,3],[2,2,4],[2,3,1],[2,3,2],[2,3,3],[2,3,4]]
```

You can see how this is similar to @Jason's approach.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need recursion since the length of the arbitrary data set is defined at the beginning at runtime:

```
var numbers = [2,3,4];
var result_array = [];
var num_product = 1;
var i=0, j=0, k=0; // iterators

for (i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
    num_product *= numbers[i];
}
for (i=0; i<num_product; i++) {
    result_array.push([]);
}
for (i=0; i<result_array.length; i++) {
    product = 1;
    for (j=0; j<numbers.length; j++) {
        k = (Math.floor(i/product)%numbers[j]) + 1;
        product *= numbers[j];
        result_array[i][j] = k;
    }
}
```

tested and functional for any number of array elements.

[A side-by-side benchmark](http://jsperf.com/recursive-vs-non-recursive-so) shows this code to be significantly faster than the recursive code - if you are *able* to avoid recursion (e.g. you know enough information up front to be able to define the whole problem) then it's better to do so, and the problem as currently defined allows you to do that.  If you're just trying to learn about recursion, then this isn't very helpful to you :)

Comment: wheres the recursion gone^^

Comment: As I commented on the original question, I think this is better suited to a non-recursive method, and my impression was that he didn't require it to be recursive, he just thought it was necessary.  Unfortunately I was a little hasty and I don't think my solution works as is anyway.  I'll come back and take another look at it later when I have a little time.

Comment: I did require it, as I posted I want it to work for *any* length of array. The 3-length array was just an example.

Comment: I fixed the algorithm, it works for any length of array, you do not require recursion.